# Conditional Show/Hide in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

I have this form in Active Admin:

```
form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  f.inputs 'Home Carousel Image' do
    f.input :name
    f.input :file, as: :file
    f.input :headline_text, as: :html_editor
    f.input :button_text
    f.input :featured_image?
    f.input :headline_text
    f.input :button_text
  end

  actions
end
```

featured_image? is a boolean. I was hoping to see if a user selects this (switching it to true), only then would the input fields for :headline_text and :button_text be displayed. Otherwise, these two fields will be hidden on the form.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just use `if`:

```rb
f.input :featured_image?
if f.object.featured_image?
  f.input :headline_text
  f.input :button_text
end
```

Use `f.object` to take instance of your model.

Comment: Thanks maxd! For some reason, I keep getting an argument error? 
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: it's in the Active Admin model: 

ArgumentError in Admin::HomeCarousel

Comment: okay, I just got it to pass without the error. but it looks like the field only appears after you hit submit and go back. it looks like other's tried using a proc?:
:if => proc{ current_user.is_admin? }

Comment: so, turns out I can hack it out with some javascript / jquery. thanks for the f.object example!